# Maximum update depth exceeded inside componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm calling a action inside my `componentDidMount` which returns a list of data. I want to access these data to do something else. So my approach was to do it inside `componentWillReceiveProps`. But i'm getting `Maximum update depth exceeded` as i need to setState to do my function. I tried doing my work inside `render` and `componentDidUpdate` as well but same result. What would be the best approach to fix this issue?

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
          const {stationCheck} = this.props;
          const page = this.props.match.params.page;
          let allowedEvcStations = nextProps.consumer.allowedEvc.chargingStations;

          allowedEvcStations && allowedEvcStations.forEach(station => {
                stationCheck(station.stationId);
          })
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add this control.

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if(prevProps.DATA!==this.props.DATA)
    this.CUSTOMACTION();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use componendDidMount lifecycle method, if it is a async call and redux is used then you should use thunk etc middleware to update your store. if it is a simple asynchrounous request from componentDidMount then you should use callback or .then (if promise is returned) to update the state.

Also componentWillReceiveProps() is deprecated in future version of React (17)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, and avoid using componentWillReceiveProps as this lifecycle method is deprecated:

In getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle method on the basis of new props you can set stationCheck array in component state.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if(props.stationCheck !== state.stationCheck) {
          return {stationCheck: props.stationCheck} // this is setState equivalent
      }
    }
```

In componentDidUpdate you can check for condition and then call your action which will bring new stationCheck array

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
if(prevProps.DATA!==this.props.DATA)  
    this.CUSTOMACTION();
}
```

Finally you can use state in render method